# Parse service name in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

If I run this command:

```
sc query state=inactive | find /i "some_service_name"
```

This is the output:

```
SERVICE_NAME: some_service_name
DISPLAY_NAME: some_service_display_name
```

How do I set only the service name into a variable?

I tried this but it's setting the value of the last line (display name) into the variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%S in ('sc query state^=inactive ^| find /i "some_service_name"') do set service=%%S
echo "%service%"
```

Comment: So why not change the `FIND` command to look for `SERVICE_NAME: some_service_name`.

Comment: Thanks, simple solution :)

Comment: Also your stated output from your provided code cannot be correct. Only line 1 of that output contains the case insensitive string `some_service_name`, so it will not output a line containing `DISPLAY_NAME: some_service_display_name` because that does not contain a matching string! In future please ensure that you use accurate data within your question. We understand that there are occasions where data may need to be obfuscated or changed for privacy or security, _(although this is not one of them)_, but when you do that, please ensure that it does not invalidate the pertinent information.